# Mouse and keyboard focus problem

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, mouse

I have two Chrome windows side by side. I click a link in window#1, ok. Now I want to switch to window#2 and click anywhere in the window.

Noting happens. Sometimes the cursor switch to make-bigger-window style.

If I click in the top part of current window. And then in the top part of next window I can switch focus so the other window works.

Another problem is that the keyboard focus can get stuck in one window. I can click on things in one window but when using the keyboard it will change the first window. Only by closing the window that has the focus, it will release keyboard.

What is this madness?

Another problem not related is that sometimes I get logged out. Just like that.

Update: I can make the mouse work outside current window sometimes by clicking my name in the upper right corner.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate.  You might find resolve your issue with the selected answer to this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/45536/window-focus-confusion-in-unity

Comment: The answer was upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 which I already use, so it didn't solve my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be something with Unity window management. I installed Gnome shell instead and by switching to Gnome Classic (no effects) I got everything to work.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

And then changed window manager at login screen.